# Reading values inside Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatables

I am using Editor Datatables and am returning data from Editor to a controler and am trying to read the values from a so-called `Dictionary<string,object>`. Can anyone advise how this is done. I read that the Dictionary needs to be Json deserialized but am not too sure how it's done. I'm including a picture of the values I'm trying to read. Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMMXT.jpg)

I read in the controller the data returned via e.Values:

```
editor.PostCreate += (sender, e) => t = Task.Run(() => Add(intContTpe, lngContIdx, e.Values));
internal static void Add(int intContTpe, long lngContIdx, object objPCEAValues)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dicVoDaCDRFormats = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (!dicPCEAValues.ContainsKey("CustomerVoiceCLICDRFormats.0"))
    {
        dicVoDaCDRFormats = ((Dictionary<string, object>)dicPCEAValues["CustomerVoiceCLICDRFormats"]);

        PrintToOutput("", ((Dictionary<string, object>)dicPCEAValues["CustomerVoiceCLICDRFormats"])["0"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have a dictionary with the required values. Why do you want to deserialize? If you want objects to be specific types just cast them.

Comment: foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> items in dicVoDaCDRFormats)
    {
        PrintToOutput("", items.Value);
    }

If I try to iterate the keyvaluepairs from dicVoDaCDRFormats I get not the values in the picture but "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each value in the `dicVoDaCDRFormats` is a dictionary it self. You need to open those dictionaries as well.

Check if this gives you the result intended.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> items in dicVoDaCDRFormats) 
{
    if (items.Value is Dictionary<string, object> innerDict)
        foreach (var item in innerDict)
            PrintToOutput("", items.Value); 
}
```

These kind of working with the `object` type is not safe. You can add type checking for other parts with the `is` and `as` keywords to be safe. But it depends on the case you are working with.

Comment: You can mark the answer. An up vote would make me happy too :)